# Need a function that describes datapoints I have

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I would like to build a function that more or less matches the below data.

It should have a maximum at $1$. To the left hand side of the maximum the decrease of the function should be rather steep. However the function should never have a $y$ value that goes below $0$. On the right hand side of the maximum the function should decrease in value not as fast as on the left side. It should never reach $y=0$ as well.

Here are some data points I used to plot my function:

```
X-Value Y-Value
0,10    0,05
0,20    0,1
0,30    0,2
0,40    0,6
0,50    0,7
0,60    0,8
0,70    0,85
0,90    0,95
1,00    1
1,10    0,95
1,20    0,85
1,30    0,8
1,40    0,75
1,50    0,7
1,80    0,68
2,00    0,65
2,50    0,6
3,00    0,57
```

[image]

This is just something I plotted using the data above. It should behave similarly, but smoother. I tried to find a couple of default parabolas, but could not find something that matches our criteria.

The question:
 - Is there a function that returns something similar to the data I provided?
 - How would that function look like?
 - Ideally I would like to be able to configure how steep the function falls after the Maximum.

Thanks!

Comment: Pade Approximants : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant You use the points to solve for the coefficients.

Comment: Invent some more points after the end to control the fall off.

Comment: What do you plan to do : interpolate or extrapolate ?

Comment: You could use a linear piecewise function with two breakpoints and fit the three intervals: $0\le x<1$, $1\le x<1.5$, $1.5\le x$. It is interesting to note that you have not sampled x at regular intervals.

Comment: What kind of fit are you looking for? Is polynomial an option?Is there any limitation for the maximum order of polynomial if so?